# What happened when I called a method from a subclass from the abstract superclass activity?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, casting

I wanted to call a subclass function from within my superclass (which extends activity). However, I couldn't find the instance of the subclass, so I just naively tried to downcast my abstract superclass and call it's method to see what would happen. I didn't expect this to work - how could the superclass know which instance to call the method on?

```
public abstract class RootActivity extends Activity{
    private flag someCondition;

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
        //... 
    }
    // ... 

    public void startJob(JobAction.Id jobaction){
        Log.d("Zlatan", "started a job");
        if (!jobaction.someCondition){
            return;
        }else{
            ((SpecificJob) this).dontDelete(); //<--- What have I done?
            startSomeLongAsynchronousJob(someCondition);
            Log.d("Zlatan", "calling finish");
            finish();
        }

    }
    // ...
    public void someOtherFunction(){
        finish();
    }
    @Override 
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        //...
        startJob(JobAction.SOMEENUM);  //Startjob is being called in the superclass
    }
}
}
```

I have a subclass here. The activity was launched by another activity and I've included the manifest snippet here too.

```
public class SpecificJob extends SomeClassThatExtendsRootActivity{
    //SomeClassThatExtendsRootActivity extends RootActivity - I've ommitted it
    private boolean flag = false;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        //...
    }
    // ... some code ...
    public void dontDelete(){ //Not static
        flag = true;
        Log.d("Zlatan", "I set flag"); //This doesn't appear in log
    }

    @Override 
    public void onDestroy(){
        Log.d("Zlatan", "When finishing, flag is now " + flag);
    }
}

<activity
        android:name=".SpecificJob"
        android:label="@string/TXT_BOOKMARKS"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/stuff"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:taskAffinity=".SpecificJob">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.me.feature.SOME_WORKFLOW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="concurrency"
            android:value="DEFAULT_CONCURRENCES|printer"
            />
    </activity>
```

To my surprise, there was no error or crash. My result was

```
D/Zlatan started a job
D/Zlatan calling finish
D/Zlatan﹕ When finishing, flag is now false
```

I dont see the log that I wrote in SpecificJob.dontDelete(). My question is

1) What did this do at runtime? Why don't I see "I set flag", and why didn't it crash?

2) How can I best call a function in SpecificJob from the RootActivity?

Comment: Where do you call startJob ?

Comment: startJob is called in several places in RootActivity, in override functions like onOptionsItemSelected and onKeyDown. This is part of my problem; I know I should intercept these in SpecificJob class, but I there are many.

Answer (score 1):

The casts are unchecked until runtime, and as you inherited SpecificJob from RootActivity and only called startJob() on SpecificJob the resulting object is still of type SpecificJob. This means it was possible to make the cast without problems. If you were to extend RootActivity and try call startJob() on this new class it wouldn't work.

You shouldn't call a subclass from a superclass. The superclass shouldn't have any knowledge of how it has been extended. There's probably a better way of doing it, how come you want to do this?

Update: So put all clean-up code that will be used by RootActivity and any class that inherits it in RootActivity's onDestroy method.

```
public abstract class RootActivity extends Activity{
    @Override 
    public void onDestroy(){
        // All cleanup code common to inherited classes goes here
    }
}
```

Then in SpecificJob call super.onDestroy and then any code that is unique to SpecificJob.

```
public class SpecificJob extends SomeClassThatExtendsRootActivity{
    @Override 
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        // All cleanup code unique to this class goes here
    }
```

}

Comment: I do some cleanup in onDestroy of SpecificJob,. However, one of the conditions in my cleanup code depends on if the activity closing was a result of the finish used in RootActivity.startJob(...), or by other means. 

My solutions were 1) Set a flag in RootActivity and get it in SpecificJob, which I didn't want to do, or 2) Intercept every call to startJob, which just is a lot of code, or 3) call a function in RootActivity to alert specificJob, which is what I've tried here.

Comment: @EricS. Well if the clean-up is dependant on which class is used (e.g RootActivity/SpecificJob/SomeClassThatExtendsRootActivity) then you should be putting the code in each one respectively then call the superclass's method. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks @mbdavis. My cleanup code is actually sends a broadcast elsewhere instead of actually 'cleaning up' - I guess it was a misnomer. Given the behemoth that I am looking at, it probably won't work but thanks anyways.

Comment: @EricS. How is the broadcast generated? This is still the route to go down to correctly use inheritance - may require some rethinking however

Answer (score 1):

Like already mentioned, this works because objects "know" their type and type casts are only checked at runtime. So if `startJob()` is called on a `SpecificJob` instance it will work. But if the method is called on an instance of another `RootActivity` subclass you will get an exception at runtime. This is also why you should avoid type casts as much as possible.

In this particular case it's easy to write the code in a type-safe manner. Simply add a declaration for the method `dontDelete()` to `RootActivity`, like this

```
protected abstract void dontDelete();
```

This forces concrete subclasses to implement the method and makes the type cast unnecessary.

Comment: I'm confused as to which SpecificJob instance it uses, and why the line in SpecificJob wasn't run. I didn't didn't specify an instance, and I thought perhaps there was some magic happening because SpecificJob is launched as a singletask activity. 

Did it use an instance of the abstract RootActivity?

Comment: Every `SpecificJob` instance is also a `RootActivity` instance. That's how inheritance works :)